# geokit-rails getting the route passing close to 2 points

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, geokit

I'm having a `route` model

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :etapes
  acts_as_mappable :through => :steps
end
```

and a `step` one (that contains lat and lgn)

```
class Step ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :route
  acts_as_mappable
end
```

Actually, I can get the routes passing close to one point with the `in_range` scope : `Route.joins(:steps).in_range(0..15, :origin => [lat, lng]).group(:id)`

I'm trying to get the `route` passing close to 2 `steps`, `acts_as_mappable` does not have the scope I need, so I'm wondering what the best way to go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to those having similar issue, I did it like this.

Given a hash with 4 points (2 lat and lng);

```
ids = Route.joins(:steps).in_range(0..15, :origin => [hash[:lat1], hash[:lng1]]).group(:id).map(&:id)
routes = Route.joins(:steps).in_range(0..15, :origin => [hash[:lat2], hash[:lng2]]).group(:id)
routes.select {|route| ids.include? route.id}
```

I first take the routes in range with my first point, then the routes in range with my second point and I select in my first routes only the one in the second routes.